# In VBA how do I get the "ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Values" to point to a specific line of a 2 dimensional array?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, graph

I have a large, 2 dimension array (600 rows x 18 columns). I can make my graph "ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Values" = a single dimension array name OK.

However, when I reference the name of the 2 dimensional array it always defaults to picking up the top row. Is there any way to make it select my chosen row?
I have tried the following:
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Values = arrayname(25,)
but no luck. 
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have more options:

---

1) **use a function to retrieve the wanted row and return it as a one-dimensional array**

```
Function Get2DArrayRow(arr2D As Variant, irow As Long) As Variant
    ReDim rowArr(LBound(arr2D, 2) To UBound(arr2D, 2)) As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    For j = LBound(arr2D, 2) To UBound(arr2D, 2)
        rowArr(j) = arr2D(irow, j)
    Next j
    Get2DArrayRow = rowArr
End Function
```

to be exploited as

```
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = Get2DArrayRow(arrayname, 3) '<-- retrieve 3rd row of your 2D array
```

---

2) **use a jagged array**

should your large 2D array derive from an excel range

```
Sub main()
    Dim arr() As Variant '<-- jagged array
    Dim i As Long
    With Range("A1:Z1000") '<-- reference the range you want to fill 2D array with 
        ReDim arr(1 To .Rows.Count) '<-- size your jagged array to match rows number only        
        For i = 1 To .Rows.Count '<-- loop through your referenced range rows
            arr(i) = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.Rows(i).Value)) '<-- fill jagged array current element with a 1D array
        Next i
    End With

    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = Application.Transpose(arr(25)) '<-- use 25th element of your jagged array
End Sub
```

Comment: @MichaelM, did you get through it?

Comment: Sorry hit return which sent message. will try to to agian.

Comment: Your first line"Function Get2DArrayRow(arr2d As Variant, irow As Long) As Variant" do I assume "arr2d" is the name of my 2 D array I have created?  Is "irow" a new array you have dimensioned?   You then "ReDim rowArr". but have not defined an array called "rowArr"?  Next line dims "i" and "j" but you only use "j" later?  In the final code "ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = Get2DArrayRow(arrayname, 3)" I know i can use an "i" for the SeriesCollection value, can I  also use a counter like "j"  for the (arrayname, j).  Sorry to ask lots of questions.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: 1) yes 2) No, iRow is a value of Long type: it's the argument of the function by which you pass the row index of arr2D you need to retrieve values of 3) ReDim acts as a first Dim 4) you can omit i declaration 5) yes. Let me know

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Its probably me being slow...  I understand 1) and 2). Thanks.     For 3) why cannot it just be "Dim rowArr"?  If I know the row length of my "arr2D" presumably I can just put in the number and not use LBound etc?  Thanks,

Comment: It's because from a general point of view `Get2DArrayRow` function can't know in advance `arr2D` sizes, so it gets them querying its bounds. You may as well substitute a _parametric_ `ReDim` with a fixed _`Dim`_, thus loosing in generality for a possible further use of this function. If I fulfilled your question, then please mark the answer as accepted. Thank you

Comment: Your comments are very much appreciated and the problem in getting it to work are all down to me as I am very in-experienced. I tried to move this conversation to Chat but I am not able to do so as i don't have enough points. Can we talk via my email address "michael.mills@m2marketing.co.uk" ? as I very much appreciate you help with this.  Thanks,

Comment: it's better to stay here so that other SO people could (hopefully) benefit from this thread. In some comments we'll automatically receive the prompt to move to chat and then we'll follow it

Comment: Got it all working...  Thanks for great help with custom Function.